# Self-adjoint operators on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=P_2(R)$ be a vector space of all real polynomials with degree equal to or less than $2$ with inner product $$\langle p,q\rangle =\int_0^1 p(x)\,q(x)\,dx$$ and $T:V\to V$ be an operator with $$T=\left(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2\right)=a_1x$$ Is $T$ self-adjoint?

Comment: Please consider learning MathJax typesetting instead of posting images with formulas in them.

Comment: What have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: What does self-adjoint mean?

Comment: can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to transcribe your question.

Answer (score 2):

The operator $T$ is *not* self-adjoint because, for instance,$$\bigl\langle T(1),x\bigr\rangle=\bigl\langle0,x\bigr\rangle=0$$but$$\bigl\langle1,T(x)\bigr\rangle=\langle1,x\rangle=\int_0^1x\,\mathrm dx=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that
$$<Tp,q>=<p,Tq>.$$
Try to get the answer: no.

Comment: Yes, I proved that it is not self-adjoint. I showed that <Tp,q>is not equal to <p,Tq>.

Comment: Thanks for all of your helpings.

Comment: @zeinab You are welcome!